# Bash Handling of Special Characters Automatically

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script that is pretty straight forward.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql_user=$1
mysql_password=$2
mysql_database=$3

mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxx -e "create database $mysql_database;grant usage on *.* to '$mysql_user'@'%' identified by '$mysql_password';grant all privileges on $mysql_database.* to '$mysql_user'@'%';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Now this script in its simplicity works perfect.

But the problem I have now experienced is that if I use a password that anyware in it has a **$** sign the whole script fails.

How can I modify my script to just automatically add a **\** in front of it when it is detected?

Comment: Do you mean the mysql_password or the -pxxxxxxx one? Also, describe how the script fails.

Comment: May be invoking the script with password argument enclosed with single quote should work. For eg., `script.sh user 'pass' data`

Comment: If you're not verifying the values used in the string passed to `mysql`, you are opening yourself to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: The -pxxxxxxxx is not the issue if someone passes ./mysql-script.sh mysql-user pa$$word Database it warps the password that has is then passed to MySQL.

For now I just want to get that working form there I will do validation of the input.

So I am looking for a way that before the password gets to the adding the user and setting the password that it will then automatically change it to pa\$\$word. I only have the issue when there is a $ sighn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `sed` to do the required escaping :

```
mysql_password=$(echo $2 | sed 's/\$/\\$/g')
```

then use it like :

```
 mysql -u root -p$mysql_password -e .......
```

Comment: I tries this but this unfortunately did not help I created a demo script to test it `#!/bin/bash

password=$(echo $1 | sed 's/\$/\\$/g')

echo "$password"
`

And when I run ./script.sh pa$$word I get the following output pa10656word

Comment: Unfortunately `$$` represents the PID of the current shell, and the echo command is causing the problem. Lemme check if I can find the cure.

Comment: It is not always going to be $$ but with the system that I am writing is where customers can choose what there password is going to be. For there mysql.

Comment: There is one way to stop it by supplying param 2 inside single quotes. Eg : ./script.sh 'pa$$word' . Regarding other special characters u can use a character class in the regex.

Comment: You just game a great idea. Rather then me doing it in BASH I could fix it firstly in PHP and then before PHP executes my SELL script I can fix it with a regular expression.

Comment: The choice is always yours. By the way, I couldn't find a cure without using the single quotes. Shame on me.